# Insert only child table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have parent class(Categories) and child class (Products). Here from the UI perspective Categories will be fixed values say(red,green,blue,orange).These information will be get entered and saved in the Categories table. Now I need to save the products relating to each categories.

Question:

1. Whether it is possible to insert only the child (products) relating it to categories.
2. What type of relationship will be suitable in the above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible to insert only the child (products) relating it to categories, like this

You can retrive Parent from database and then save its child

```
String hql = "from Categories where color = red";
            Query query= session.createQuery(hql);
            List<Categories> list = query.list();
            Categories categories = list.get(0);

            Products products = new Products();
            products.setName("");
            // save other attributes
            products.setCategories(products);
            session.save(products);
```

Here You can save your products under parent of red.

- One to Many relation is Best for this scenario.